# no kind "KubeSchedulerConfiguration" is registered for version "kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta3"

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to apply KubeSchedulerConfiguration but getting below error, Can anybody give direction?

K8s version: 1.21.14
Bootstrap tool: kind

scheduler-config.yaml

```
apiVersion: kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta3
kind: KubeSchedulerConfiguration

profiles:
  - schedulerName: default-scheduler
    pluginConfig:
      - name: PodTopologySpread
        args:
          defaultConstraints:
            - maxSkew: 1
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
              whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
          defaultingType: List
```

Error log

```
root@kind-control-plane:/etc/kubernetes/manifests# cat /var/log/containers/kube-scheduler-kind-control-plane_kube-system_kube-scheduler-31d58a4a4df5ae2d71afa2508797e9026987ca61c82cf047007ae642cfb3a688.log
2022-10-31T09:10:41.6436638Z stderr F I1031 09:10:41.643531       1 serving.go:347] Generated self-signed cert in-memory
2022-10-31T09:10:41.643702592Z stderr F no kind "KubeSchedulerConfiguration" is registered for version "kubescheduler.config.k8s.io/v1beta3" in scheme "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/scheduler/apis/config/scheme/scheme.go:30"
root@kind-control-plane:/etc/kubernetes/manifests#
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Scheduler Configuration docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/scheduling/config/):

> Note: KubeSchedulerConfiguration v1beta2 is deprecated in v1.25 and will be removed in v1.28. KubeSchedulerConfiguration **v1beta3** is deprecated in v1.26 and will be removed in v1.29. **Please migrate KubeSchedulerConfiguration to v1**.